# Doctrine ORM, Coalesce in JoinColumn

Tags: doctrine-orm

Do we at this moment have a way to use coalesce in the join column for relations?

For example a car has many parts. A car can have a relation to itself. I want to make demo cars, which refer to another car (the original car). But i do not want to copy all the parts of the car. So i would like to join using Coalesce. `join part.car_id = coalesce(car.car_id, car.id)`. So we would use the coalesce to first check if the car as a car_id, referring to the original car, if so, its a demo car and we use the car id of the original car. If not than use the car's own id. For example when calling the original car.

If this would not be possible using the Annotations. Would it be possible in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to define conditions on doctrine association. Association is always defined between concrete entities and fields.
It also doesn't work with constrains in relational databases.

I think you should use different design to achieve it. I would recommend to introduce new entity `Model` and associate `parts` to this entity and then have a `Car` which is also associated to the `Model`.

Comment: Accepted as answer because it's not possible. The suggested implementation does not really do what the case described tough. But thanks for your comment.